# null pointer exception in array

Tags: java

I am getting a null exception error from this segment of code and I am not sure what  causing it. The array itemcatalog has being populate for i =0 to 8. I am new to java so any assistance will be greatly appreciated. The error message points to the line of the while statement. Thanks

```
public class ItemCatalog {

   private static ItemCatalog instance = new ItemCatalog(); 
   private Item itemCatalog[] = new Item[9];

   private ItemCatalog(){
   };

   public static synchronized ItemCatalog getInstance() {
   return instance;
   }

   public void populateCatalog()
   {  
      itemCatalog[0] = new Item("bb","Baked Beans",new BigDecimal("0.35"));
      itemCatalog[1] = new Item("cf","Cornflakes",new BigDecimal("1.00"));
      itemCatalog[2] = new Item("s0","Sugar",new BigDecimal("0.50"));
      itemCatalog[3] = new Item("tb","Tea Bags",new BigDecimal("1.15"));
      itemCatalog[4] = new Item("ic","Instant Coffee",new BigDecimal("2.50"));
      itemCatalog[5] = new Item("b0","Bread",new BigDecimal("0.50"));
      itemCatalog[6] = new Item("s0","Sausages",new BigDecimal("1.30"));
      itemCatalog[7] = new Item("e0","Eggs",new BigDecimal("0.75"));
      itemCatalog[8] = new Item("m0","Milk",new BigDecimal("0.65"));
   }

   public BigDecimal getPrice(String itemCode)
   {  

      int i = 0;
      while (!itemCode.equals(itemCatalog[i].getItemCode()))
      {
        i++;
      }
      BigDecimal itemPrice = itemCatalog[i].getItemprice();
   return itemPrice;
   }
}
```

I solved the issue. I was populating the catalog in the main class which was giving the null exception error. I instantiate it in the jframe instead and it works. The follow code solved the issue, but is this the best place to populate the catalog?

```
private void saleButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

        String itemCode = this.itemCodeinput.getText();
        int itemQuantity =Integer.parseInt(this.itemQuantityinput.getText());

        ItemCatalog catalog = ItemCatalog.getInstance();

        catalog.populateCatalog(); 
        BigDecimal price = catalog.getPrice(itemCode);
        itemCostoutput.setText(price.toString());
}
```

Comment: Post the full stack trace. That will be helpful

Comment: Are you sure the passed itemCode is not null ?

Comment: Either `itemCode` is null, or `itemCatalog[i]` is null.

Comment: Regarding the stack trace : tell us where is the line in error.

Comment: Try [using the built-in debugger](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html)!

Comment: Which line? Use a debugger to see the values of `itemCode` and `itemCatalog[i]` and `itemCatalog[i].getItemCode()`

Comment: And that `itemCatalog` is in scope, and that there are no null-return cases for `getItemPrice`?

Comment: you should use a `for` loop, and `itemCatalog.length`.

Comment: It's a broken design, in that if itemCode is never matched you'll walk off the end of the array.

Comment: If your itemCode isn't in the array, the loop can only stop with an exception.

Comment: "populate for i =1 to 10" ? Not from 0 to 9 ?

Answer (score 2):

If your itemCode doesn't match any entries in your itemCatalog, then eventually

```
  while (!itemCode.equals(itemCatalog[i].getItemCode()))
  {
      i++;
  }
```

will increment i to 11, in which case itemCatalog[11] is either empty or out of bounds.

If addition, you should use a for loop to iterate through the itemCatalog:

```
for (int i = 0; i < itemCatalog.length; i++) {
    if (itemCode.equals(itemCatalog[i].getItemCode()) {
        return (BigDecimal) itemCatalog[i].getItemprice();
    }
}

return null // you can change this from null to a flag 
            // value for not finding the item.
```

Comment: Also note the original comment: he's populating from 1 - 10.  There's no assurance that itemCatalog[0] isn't null.

Comment: That's a good point, I just assumed he meant the first 10 items without considering that he might have skipped 0 in his implementation

Comment: Thanks alot for everyone's comments thus far. I changed out my while loop with the for loop and still get a null point exception at the if statement line.

Answer (score 0):

How do you end your loop?
Seems that the loop will keep going until i is 10. Then your will have exceeded the limit.

Unless this is a uni assignment where you have to use arrays, I'd also suggest using a map, rather than an array. This way your lookup will be the same time, whether your collection has 100,000 entries or 10.

You will also reduce risk of NPE or ArrayOutOfBounds exception

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

When adding the object use the item code as the key. Then lookup by the key.

The cost of using a map is increased memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, it's clear the design isn't sound.

Here's a possible solution :

```
public BigDecimal getPrice(String itemCode) {  
      for (int i=0; i<itemCatalog.length; i++) { // not going outside the array
          if (itemCatalog[i].getItemCode().equals(itemCode)) { // inversing the test to avoid npe if itemCode is null
             return itemCatalog[i].getItemprice();
          }
      }
      return null; // default value
}
```

This supposes your array is correctly filled with itemCatalogs having an itemCode.